# Mathjax rendering bug in Recent Questions page when excess content is replaced by ellipsis

Tags: feature-request, bug

**Problem:**

[image]

The recent questions page tries to show a part of the content when the content is too big to be displayed fully. When a mathjax statement begins but is ended by the ellipsis, the mathjax statement appears instead of the actual equation.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Remove the mathjax statement completely if it is going to be broken
   by the ellipsis.
2. Display the mathjax statement completely even if it exceeds the character limit.

Comment: I feel this is a "feature request" type question(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) which is better suited for Meta SE (http://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is this actually, really, honestly, that terrible?

Comment: We can make things perfect?

Comment: Personally, I use the [main page](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) (i.e., not the /questions page) to look for questions, so I don't ever see these ellipses. Or question text, just titles & tags

Comment: Asked and got no love on Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197817/

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281522/